# Transparent Box shadow background in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, box-shadow

I have this following input field

```
input:-webkit-autofill, select:-webkit-autofill, textarea:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #2b2029 inset;
}
```

Please find the image given in the url [Box Shadow background in chrome for input field not working](http://screencast.com/t/gySj8n4DL). A picture tells thousand times more than a word.

[image]

**rgba(0,0,0,0)** and **transparent** not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am new to stack and i have edited this to my best to but the code cannot be verifiable since it involves other dependencies.

Comment: @Parthee  hey dude may try by adding the display property with box-shadow property may it work for you

Comment: Then perhaps you could make a demo that doesn't require these dependencies that still shows the same issue,

Comment: try to add `box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #2b2029 inset;` with that class